Problem with java TransferHandler and @NonNullByDefault
Most of our code packages have a package-info.java that specifies @NonNullByDefault.
(This has drastically reduced the number of NullPointerExceptions we encounter)
I now need to write a TransferHandler for a class - but it seems impossible to do if @NonNullByDefault is in effect.  This code shows the issue:
private static class ProductTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(final @Nullable TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(final TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {

        if (!info.isDrop()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}

Both of the methods are marked as an error in eclipse:
Illegal redefinition of parameter info, inherited method from TransferHandler does not constrain this parameter

It doesn't matter if the @Nullable is there or not.  Same error either way.
Is there ANY way to do this with @NonNullByDefault in effect?  Or do I have to move this class to it's own file in some other package just to NOT do that?
